Benefits of using quantum encrypted keys
Considering, in a perfect world everyone has the capability to create a quantum key. What would the benefits of using quantum encrypted keys instead of using classically encrypted keys? Besides the collapse of the wave function when someone eavesdrops.

A classical asymetric cipher is based on computationaly hard problems (assumed to be as so far we have not found an efficient algorithm). This means that classical computer is believed to be incapable of breaking the cipher in reasonable time.
A notoric example of such cipher is RSA. It is based on factoring of integers to primes. The best known (it is not ruled out that it cannot be found in the future) classical algorithm can break RSA in time exponential in number of digits of factored integer. However, there is also quantum Shor algorithm which can do so in polynomial (i.e. reasonable) time.
In theory, only possible way to have safe crypto system is to use a random ciphering key. Such key in unbreakable despite computational power you have at your disposal. But a problem is how to distribute such key classically (you have to distribute the key physically via trustful persons which is unpractical). Fortunatelly, quantum mechanics allows to construct so-called quantum key distribution. See more here (BB84 protocol).
So, the main benefit is that quantum mechanics allows to construct unbreakable ciphering system unconditionally.
However, I said in theory. There are some subtle technical issues. See paper on them here.
